# Convert Text "Date Monday, April 30, 2018 " to Numeric format MM/DD/YY 04/30/18

Tags: google-sheets

---

Date        Conversion Formula

[Link to Data Souce](https://markets.ft.com/data/funds/tearsheet/historical?s=GB0033507467:GBP) 
https://markets.ft.com/data/funds/tearsheet/historical?s=GB0033507467:GBP

**I get Data from the  Financial Times  (Link  above >> The Date is in the Text format

" **Monday, April 30, 2018** " as  shown in cell B2 above )
I need to convert the Text format in a Google Spreadsheet
to numeric format MM/DD/YY ( American Date Format )
In Excel Spreadsheet this formula conversion of  the Text Date        **"Monday, April 30, 2018" to MM/DD/YY** is done by the formula  below

=DATE(RIGHT(B2,4),MONTH(TRIM(MID(B2,FIND(", ",B2)+1,LEN(B2)-FIND(", ",B2)-9))&0),LEFT(RIGHT(B2,8),2))** 
In Google Spreadsheet

Could you please tell me how to convert the Text Format " Monday, April 30, 2018 to Numeric format MM/DD/YY 04/30/18
**Please note the commas between Monday , April 30 , 2018**

Thank you in advance
Derek

Answer (score 2):

Unlike Excel,

```
Monday, April 30, 2018
```

is already a date in [google-spreadsheet](/questions/tagged/google-spreadsheet). Click Format and Change Number format to your preferred date format.

Comment: Hi Stackoverflow
Thank you very much for your very clear answer to my question
google spreadsheet makes it so easy (unlike the formula I used in Excel)
Best regards
Derek